# Javascript not being used and object reference error on submit of form with attached model

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I am working on a password reset functionality for a website that updates a users password in a backend database. I am successfully able to change a users password by entering a strong password i.e. Password123! and the MVC architecture is happy enough when entering a password not weak enough i.e. abc but when I put in a password and confirmation that do not match i.e. Password123! and Password1234! then I am getting an error relating an object reference error for the following line:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Reset", "Reset", new { qString = Model.QueryString } ))
```

Here is my code in full:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@model ......ResetModel

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#close').click(function (event) {
        closeAjax();

        event.cancelBubble = true;
        event.returnValue = false;
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#index").validate({
        rules: {
            password: {
                required: true, minlength: 6
            },
            confirmpassword: {
                required: true, equalTo: "#password", minlength: 6
            }
        },
        messages: {
            password: "Please enter your new password.",
            c_password: "Please confirm your new password."

        }
    });
});

</script>
<div class="form_container">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href=""><img class="logo" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/SP_Logo_white.png")" alt="Cloud"/></a>
    </div>
        <div class="reset">
           <h3>Password Reset</h3>
         <div class="reset-help">
      <p>Forgot your password? Use the form to change or reset your password.</p>
    </div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Reset", "Reset", new { qString = Model.QueryString } ))
    {
    <label for="reset">UserName:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" /><br />
    <label for="password">New Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" /><br />
    <label for="confirmpassword">Confirm Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="confirmpassword" name="confirmpassword" />
    <p><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
    }
</div>
</div>
```

Can someone please help me to understand why this is happening only when the passwords do not match, I also cannot understand why my javascript validation is not being set

Rendered HTML is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Password Reset</title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="/2.jpg" alt="Big Pic" class="bg" />
    <div class="top_40"></div>

        <section id="main">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#close').click(function (event) {
            closeAjax();

            event.cancelBubble = true;
            event.returnValue = false;
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#index").validate({
            rules: {
                password: {
                    required: true, minlength: 6
                },
                c_password: {
                    required: true, equalTo: "#password", minlength: 6
                }
            },
            messages: {
                password: "Please enter your new password.",
                c_password: "Please confirm your new password."

            }
        });
    });

</script>
<div class="form_container">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href=""><img class="logo" src="/Content/SP_Logo_white.png" alt="Cloud"/></a>
    </div>
        <div class="reset">
          <h3>Password Reset</h3>
        <div class="reset-help">
          <p>Forgot your password? Use the form to change or reset your password.</p>
        </div>
<form action="/Reset/Reset?qString=qKkQBXYEsY0GthEqFIuWYfXQ1CKcUioxpbY8vfhqN9nlOcHrZdLIYzxxhtV0YK73" method="post">        <label for="reset">UserName:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" /><br />
        <label for="password">New Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" /><br />
        <label for="confirmpassword">Confirm Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="confirmpassword" name="confirmpassword" />
        <p><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>    </div>
    </div>

        </section>
        <div class="bottom_80"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show the _rendered_ HTML of your form since jQuery Validate is "Client-Side" code.

Comment: Sorry I am relatively new to all of this and I am not sure how I could go about that

Comment: In your browser, on the page in question, "view source".

Comment: Yes I have edited my comment to show this Sparky

Answer (score 1):

You have several major issues that would prevent the jQuery Validate plugin from functioning at all.

**1)** You have not added the Validate plugin `script` includes into your code.  Someplace *after* your jquery `script` includes, you should have something like this...

```
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**2)** You have attached `.validate()` to `$('#index')`.  I do not see `id="index"` anyplace on your page.  `index` would need to be the `id` of the `form` element if you want `.validate()` to function properly.  Example:

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#formID').validate({
        ...
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="formID">
    ...
```

**3)** You've incorrectly selected your "confirm password" field inside `.validate()` as `c_password`.  This key **must** match the `name` attribute of the field, which is really `confirmpassword` as per your HTML.

```
<input type="password" id="confirmpassword" name="confirmpassword" />
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/6RHDP/**

Comment: Hi Sparky, thank you for the feedback it is greatly appreciated, I have had a look at your comments and have tried to fix these errors but as yet have still been unable to validate as expected. I have tried to set the id to "index" but it does not seem to be working. Can you please look at my ammended code.

Comment: @Jay, 1. Please edit/amend your question with any new code.  This section is only for answers.  2.  Again, only the _rendered_ HTML is relevant for troubleshooting JavaScript.

Comment: @Jay, regarding my item #1 in my answer, did you also upload the script to this location? ->  `/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js`